# Error is thrown but Jest's `toThrow()` does not capture the error

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

Here is my error codes:

```
 FAIL  build/__test__/FuncOps.CheckFunctionExistenceByString.test.js
  ● 
    expect(CheckFunctionExistenceByStr(
      'any string', 'FunctionThatDoesNotExistsInString'
    )).toThrow();


    Function FunctionThatDoesNotExistsInString does not exists in string.

      at CheckFunctionExistenceByStr (build/FuncOps.js:35:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (build/__test__/FuncOps.CheckFunctionExistenceByString.test.js:12:51)
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
          at <anonymous>
```

As you can see the error did indeed occurred: `Function FunctionThatDoesNotExistsInString does not exists in string.`. However it is not captured as a pass in Jest.

Here is my codes:

```
test(`
    expect(CheckFunctionExistenceByStr(
      'any string', 'FunctionThatDoesNotExistsInString'
    )).toThrow();
  `, () => {
    expect(CheckFunctionExistenceByStr(
      'any string', 'FunctionThatDoesNotExistsInString'
    )).toThrow();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`expect(fn).toThrow()` expects a function `fn` that, **when called**, throws an exception.

However you are calling `CheckFunctionExistenceByStr` immediatelly, which causes the function to throw before running the assert.

Replace

```
test(`
    expect(CheckFunctionExistenceByStr(
      'any string', 'FunctionThatDoesNotExistsInString'
    )).toThrow();
  `, () => {
    expect(CheckFunctionExistenceByStr(
      'any string', 'FunctionThatDoesNotExistsInString'
    )).toThrow();
  }
);
```

with

```
test(`
    expect(() => {
      CheckFunctionExistenceByStr(
        'any string', 'FunctionThatDoesNotExistsInString'
      )
    }).toThrow();
  `, () => {
    expect(() => {
      CheckFunctionExistenceByStr(
        'any string', 'FunctionThatDoesNotExistsInString'
      )
    }).toThrow();
  }
);
```

Comment: This helps: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tothrowerror  -- Encapsulate the method you are actually want to test inside another function. Place that outer function inside expect() without calling it (no trailing parenthesis).

Answer (score 46):

Jest needs a callback function here. Instead of passing the function definition like this:

```
expect(yourFunction(args)).toThrow(ErrorTypeOrErrorMessage)
```

Do this:

```
expect(() => yourFunction(args)).toThrow(ErrorTypeOrErrorMessage)
```

If you don't need to pass arguments you can also do:

```
expect(yourFunction).toThrow(ErrorTypeOrErrorMessage)
```

And for asynchronous functions:

```
expect(async () => await yourFunction(args)).rejects.toThrow(ErrorTypeOrErrorMessage)
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me from pulling all my hair out!

Comment: I think they should add this to their documentation.

Comment: I also had to change my code from `.rejects` to `.toThrow` but the arrow function is required as well.

Answer (score 9):

had a similar issue but my function to be tested is async and hence your expect have to look like this:

`await expect(async () => {await myFunctionToBeTested();}).rejects.toThrow('My Error message')`

the solution I got from [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5018#issuecomment-349444674)

*Note:*

> the await before expect I added 'cause Eslint was complaining but would work without it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that the function I was testing was a getter that was immediately executed even when omitting the `()`. Wrapping the getter in a closure (`() => {myClass.get}`) fixed the problem.